# Error when plotting Linear regression - attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

here is the code:-

```
A<- as.factor(Fire)
X <- as.numeric(Length_in_meter)
No_of_parrots <- as.numeric(No_of_parrots)

model <- aov(No_of_parrots ~ X*A)
summary(model)


par(cex=1.5)
plot(X, No_of_parrots, type = "n" , las=1,
     xlab = "Length in meter" , ylab = "No_of_parrots")
SA <- split(X , A)
SY <- split(No_of_parrots , A)
for (i in 1:nlevels(A)) points(SA[[i]], SY[[i]], pch = i-1)
for (i in 1:nlevels(No_of_parrots)) abline(lm(SY[[i]] ~ SA[[i]]),  lty=1 )
```

then I got this output:

```
Error in SY[[i]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

R plotted a graph with only one regression line, but there is suppose to have two. Can you please help when I have done wrong? Thanks,

Comment: @AllanCameron it's my typo. thanks for checking anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** `for (i in 1:nlevels(No_of_parrots))` is *probably* a typo; you probably meant `for (i in 1:nlevels(A))`.

`nlevels()` is only relevant for factor variables. By using `as.numeric()`, you made sure that it was *not* a factor (even if it started out as one), hence `nlevels()` will return 0, e.g.

```r
parrots <- factor(1:3)
nlevels(as.numeric(parrots))  ## 0
```

When you run a loop over `1:nlevels(...)`, this evaluates to `1:0` → `c(1, 0)` (this is one reason that `seq(n)` is generally recommended over `1:n`). The first time through the loop you select the first elements of `SA` and `SY`. The second time through (`i==0`) you try to select the zeroth elements, which throws the error (I get a slightly different error, "attempt to select less than one element in get1index ", but that may be due to a different R version or something — the concept is the same).

Comment: thanks! I'm a new use and still learning the community guideline.